# Why my tableView stretch out?

Tags: ios, uitableview, xib

I create a LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView and on it there is a tableView and a backgroundView, 
I can use the LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView as the popup View, in my project.

This is the directory of it:

the LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView have ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader and LMLUpspringPeriodCell, all of them I create a XIB:

[image]

And In the LMLUpspringPeriodCell, I add the constraints to the name label, so it must be on the centre of the LMLUpspringPeriodCell:

[image]

But however, when I show the LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView as popup view, there comes an issue:

The tableView seems strech out of the screen.

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

My tableView's constraints is like this:

[image]

My code is below:

LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView.h:

```
typedef void(^LMLUpspringBlock)();

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView : UIView
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *upspringBackView;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UITableView *tableView;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *bottom_tableView;

@property (nonatomic, copy) LMLUpspringBlock block;

- (void)showSelf;
- (void)hideSelf;

@end
```

LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView.m:

```
#import "LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView.h"
#import "LMLUpspringPeriodCell.h"
#import "ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader.h"

@interface LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView () <UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource>

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet NSLayoutConstraint *width_tableView;

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSArray *title_arr;

@end

@implementation LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

- (void)awakeFromNib {

    [super awakeFromNib];
    //_width_tableView.constant = KWidth;
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 4;
}

- (UIView *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView viewForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader *header = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;

    header.cancel_block = ^() {

        [self hideSelf];
    };

    return header;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {


    LMLUpspringPeriodCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"LMLUpspringPeriodCell"];
    if (cell == nil) {

        cell = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LMLUpspringPeriodCell" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
    }

    // 配置cell
    cell.title_label.text = self.title_arr[indexPath.row];

    if (indexPath.row == 3) {

        cell.bottom_line.hidden = YES;
    }

    [self setNeedsLayout];
    [self layoutIfNeeded];

    return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    return 44;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForHeaderInSection:(NSInteger)section {

    return 48;
}


- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    [tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];

    LMLUpspringPeriodCell *cell = [tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];

    NSString *period_str = cell.title_label.text;

    self.block(period_str);

    [self hideSelf];
}

#pragma mark - action

- (void)showSelf {

    self.hidden = NO;
    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.5 animations:^{

        _bottom_tableView.constant = -49;
        _upspringBackView.alpha = 0.3f;
    }];

}

- (void)hideSelf {


    _bottom_tableView.constant = -_tableView.bounds.size.height - 49;

    [UIView animateWithDuration:0.25 animations:^{

        _upspringBackView.alpha = 0.f;
        [self layoutIfNeeded];
    } completion:^(BOOL finished) {

        if (finished) {

            self.hidden = YES;
        }
    }];

}

- (IBAction)tapBackView:(id)sender {

    [self hideSelf];
}

#pragma mark - setter

-(NSArray *)title_arr {


    if (!_title_arr) {

        _title_arr = @[@"当天", @"最近一周", @"最近一个月", @"最近三个月"];
    }

    return _title_arr;
}

@end
```

The ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void(^CancelChooseUpspringView)();


@interface ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader : UIView

@property (nonatomic, copy) CancelChooseUpspringView cancel_block;


@end
```

The ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader.m:

```
#import "ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader.h"

@implementation ChoosePeriodTableViewHeader

/*
// Only override drawRect: if you perform custom drawing.
// An empty implementation adversely affects performance during animation.
- (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect {
    // Drawing code
}
*/

// 取消
- (IBAction)cancel:(UIButton *)sender {

    self.cancel_block();
}
```

The LMLUpspringPeriodCell.h:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

typedef void(^ConfirmChoosePeriod)(NSString *);

@interface LMLUpspringPeriodCell : UITableViewCell

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title_label;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *bottom_line;

@property (nonatomic, copy) ConfirmChoosePeriod confirm_block;

@end
```

The LMLUpspringPeriodCell.m:

```
#import "LMLUpspringPeriodCell.h"

@implementation LMLUpspringPeriodCell

- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Initialization code
}

- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
}

@end
```

I have tried use the below code in the `awakeFromNib` method in the `LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView.m`(you can see the LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView.m code, there is annotation in the awakeFromNib method ):

```
_width_tableView.constant = KWidth;
```

Replace of the `tableView` using `trailling` to constraint the tableView, it still strech out, but use the below code :

```
_width_tableView.constant = KWidth / 2;
```

It is perfect in iPhone7, but have issue in iPhone7 Plus:

<kbd>[image]</kbd>

So, it is a very strange issue here, how to do with that?

Not enough, there is **second issue**, the last item can not click, I don't know if is related to the tabbar.

How to solve the two issue? Thanks in advance.

---

**EDIT -1**

I add the LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView to the kwyWindow on a VC:

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView *upspring_v;

....
[[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.upspring_v];
```

---

**EDIT -2**

This is my PurchaseRecordVC.m, in there I show the `LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView`:

```
#import "PurchaseRecordVC.h"
#import "LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView.h"


@interface PurchaseRecordVC ()

@property (nonatomic, strong) LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView *upspring_v;


@end

@implementation PurchaseRecordVC

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];

    [self initData];
    [self initUI];
}

#pragma mark - init

- (void)initData {

}

- (void)initUI {

    // 添加界面

    [[UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow addSubview:self.upspring_v];

}

#pragma mark - Navigation

// In a storyboard-based application, you will often want to do a little preparation before navigation
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender {
    // Get the new view controller using [segue destinationViewController].
    // Pass the selected object to the new view controller.
}


- (IBAction)clickTheChoosePeriod:(UIButton *)sender {

    [_upspring_v showSelf];
}

#pragma mark - getter

- (LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView *)upspring_v {

    if (!_upspring_v) {

        _upspring_v = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView" owner:self options:nil].firstObject;
        // 初始化
        _upspring_v.upspringBackView.alpha = 0;
        _upspring_v.bottom_tableView.constant = -_upspring_v.tableView.bounds.size.height - 49;
        _upspring_v.hidden = YES;
        _upspring_v.block = ^(NSString *period){

        };
    }

    return _upspring_v;
}



#pragma mark - dealloc

- (void)dealloc {

    // 移除界面
    [self.upspring_v removeFromSuperview];
}

@end
```

Comment: what is the issue can elaborate more ?

Comment: @KKRocks tableView seems strech out of the screen.

Comment: can you add screenshot ?

Comment: @KKRocks I add, maybe the network affect, it did not show? I can see the snapshoots.

Comment: can you add LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView files ?

Comment: @KKRocks Do you mean the xib file?

Comment: LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView is this library ?

Comment: @KKRocks I add, above my code is the xib's file, you can see that.

Comment: how to add LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView in view ?

Comment: @KKRocks I add the LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView to the window. see my edit post.

Comment: try to change width in showSelf function .

Comment: Could you show the code in your ViewController where you are showing the  LMLUpspringChoosePeriodView?

Comment: @RimonRagaie See my EDIT -2

Answer (score 0):

I created a playground satisfying the same conditions, but altered it a bit for you to use as an example

Here you go:

https://wetransfer.com/downloads/7cf7267e51b7d265204a3ceaed48d0fd20170424125153/c92374